# Getting 401 Unauthorized when call post request in Lambda Python

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I use the code below to call post request in Lambda and Pycharm:

```
def save_log(event=None, context=None):
  headers = {
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  }
  params = {
      'service_id': 12,
      'account': 'abc',
      'password': 'abc123'
  }
  url = "https://url/api/auth"
  resp = requests.post(url, data=params, headers=headers)
  print(resp.content)
  return {
      'statusCode': 200,
  }
```

But it only work on Pycharm, not Lambda. In Lambda, I got "401 Unauthorized" when calling this.
I have added "requests" package to Lambda.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Does your API Manager include an authorization?

Comment: @xion What is API Manager? Is it in Lambda?

Comment: Sorry, should be API gateway, your lambda function should have an API Gateway to serve as your endpoint? there might had some authorizer setup. Your call to the endpoint should reach API gateway, before reaching your lambda function.